# jQuery attr does not seem to return string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code :

JS:

```
var test2 = ['RMrpi5Z8doc','JIPbUaqyYx0','MbjXYg0YRmw'];

    $('tr').live('click', function(event){
      $($(this).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function() { 
        if (!((this == 'even') || (this == 'odd'))) {
            alert(jQuery.inArray(this, test2));
            if (this == 'RMrpi5Z8doc') {
              alert(this);
            }
        }   
      });
    });
```

HTML :

```
  <table>
   <tr class="odd RMrpi5Z8doc">
     <td>Kite</td>
     <td>Just Like Vinyl</td>
     <td>Audiotree</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

inArray does not match and returns -1.  The if statement matching the literal string does match.  If I substitute in the literal in inArray, that also matches.

I've seen a post which said that jQuery attr does not return strings anymore, but looking at the documentation for attr on the jQuery site  seems to say it does.

Perhaps I should be going about this an entirely different way?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: *"Perhaps I should be going about this an entirely different way?"* I would suggest not using class to store this value. You could instead use `data-id` or if they are unique, simply `id` should work.

Comment: While you're thinking of reworking code, note that `.live()` has been deprecated for some time now.  If you're working with up-to-date jQuery you should be using the `.on()` API.

Answer (score 6):

You're using the wrong `each`. You meant [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), the general-purpose iterator:

```
$.each($(this).attr('class').split(' '), function ...);
```

not [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), the instance function on jQuery instances:

```
$($(this).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function ...); // Wrong
```

In particular, what's happening is this part of the above:

```
$($(this).attr('class').split(' '))
```

...calls `$()` with the array, which doesn't do what you want it to do. :-)

Comment: ... or just `$.each(this.className.split(' '), function ... )`

Comment: @raina77ow: Indeed, I was making minimal changes, but I absolutely advocate using the direct reflected properties (`this.className` rather than `$(this).attr('class')`) whenever the property is reliable (and `className` is).

Comment: Also `.attr("class")` won't work in old versions of IE, I don't think.

Comment: Thanks, while I am not using split nor each anymore, I bet I will be running into this in the future.

Comment: @Pointy: Hasn't jQuery handled that since v1.0?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well since the changes in 1.6 (the introduction of `.prop()` specifically) I think it may not.  I haven't tried it however and I confess to being somewhat uninterested in doing so :-)

Comment: @Pointy: 1.6.0 had some issues, but 1.6.1 and above fix them (1.6.0 broke ***way*** too much code) and 1.5.x and below are fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a type mismatch. If you switch to `if (this === 'RMrpi5Z8doc') {`, the second alert will no longer fire. Using `this.toString()` will solve this problem, as will the following:

```
$.each($(this).attr('class').split(' '), function() { 
    //...etc.
```

This is, by the way, an unusual way of doing this. Normally, you would test for a class with the `hasClass` method:

```
$('tr').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('odd')) {
        //...
```

Also, as raina77ow notes, there are the `:even` and `:odd` pseudoclasses:

```
$('tr').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':odd')) {
        //...
```

This way, you could dispense with your `odd` and `even` classes entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored this using :

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function(){
  alert(jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('id'), test2));
}
```

Which seems to work.  I have moved the class name to an id field since I'm not using these identifiers for any stylesheets, they really are ids.